# Edit specific line in a file with lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to edit a **specific** line in a file using lua.
For example, I have a file with 12 lines. I want to edit the 2nd line ONLY.
Line 1: Hello
Line 2: Hello again
The output file would be for example
Line 1: Hello
Line 2: Whatever
but without caring what's the content of the 2nd line. Just by the number of the line.

Comment: This is a rather simple question but there isn't an answer for it in the forum. I only found questions with specific string edits, where they search for the string and replace it. I want to search with line numbers.

Comment: https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-file:lines

Comment: I've tried this but I must be doing something wrong because I can't get it to work.

Comment: If you could provide some working code that utilizes this I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out after all. Here's the code:

```
function Initialize()

    inputFile = 'PathToFile'

end
function Edit()

    local file = io.open(inputFile, 'r')
    local fileContent = {}
    for line in file:lines() do
        table.insert (fileContent, line)
    end
    io.close(file)

    fileContent[3] = 'This line has been edited'

    file = io.open(inputFile, 'w')
    for index, value in ipairs(fileContent) do
        file:write(value..'\n')
    end
    io.close(file)
end
```